# csrutil disable: command not found El Capitan

Tags: macos, permission, sip

I was using a SATA HDD running Yosemite on a MBP 2012.
I installed a SSD drive with El Capitan.

I took out the DVD optical drive and replaced it with a drive case for the HDD.
Now when I am running the SSD, I cannot access some of the HDD folders. I would like to access them.

I tried the usual disabling of SIP - `csrutil disable` and I get *the command not found*.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is **not** SIP's purpose to disable or enable access to folders!

Comment: SIP was introduced with El Cap. If the recovery partition was only Yosemite, that would account for the command not being found. The question is otherwise unclear anyway as to exactly what was done & what results were seen. SIP is a red herring, imo.

Comment: OK, how do I enable access to folders? And if I use either drive, I cannot access the other folders found on the other drive.

Comment: What prevents you? How far down the hierarchy can you get, or does the drive not mount at all? We really need more detail, right now it's very hard to tell quite what you mean.

Comment: I gave up.I bought a new hard drive, took the old one out which had my previous OS and have it connected via USB, and put in the new one (now alongside the SSD drive running El Cap). I can get into that via USB. Cheers.